# Rails validating full_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, validating

Hey... how would you validate a full_name field (name surname).

Comment: need some good reg for validates_format_of

Comment: What are the acceptable values, and what are not? To my mind you can check only, that there should not be any special chars like `#@%...`, numbers and should be at least 1 space.

Comment: Some people go by a single name, so even looking for a space can be problematic. Ask yourself: *Why* am I validating a name field? What problem are you trying to prevent from occurring?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Consider names like:

- Ms. Jan Levinson-Gould
- Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr.
- Brett d'Arras-d'Haudracey
- Brüno

Instead of validating the characters that are there, you might just want to ensure some set of characters is *not* present.

#### For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_format_of :full_name, :with => /\A[^0-9`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]+\z/
  # add any other characters you'd like to disallow inside the [ brackets ]
  # metacharacters [, \, ^, $, ., |, ?, *, +, (, and ) need to be escaped with a \

end
```

#### Tests

```
Ms. Jan Levinson-Gould         # pass
Dr. Martin Luther King, Jr.    # pass
Brett d'Arras-d'Haudracey      # pass
Brüno                          # pass
John Doe                       # pass
Mary-Jo Jane Sally Smith       # pass
Fatty Mc.Error$                # fail
FA!L                           # fail
#arold Newm@n                  # fail
N4m3 w1th Numb3r5              # fail
```

---

#### Regular expression explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^`!@#\$%\^&*+_=\d]+     any character except: '`', '!', '@', '#',
                           '\$', '%', '\^', '&', '*', '+', '_', '=',
                           digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Comment: I found this issue on Rails 4.0.1

The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

But it was solved with adding :multiline => true
``validates_format_of :name, :with => /^[^0-9`!@#\$%\^&*+_=]+$/, :multiline => true``

Comment: @barek2k2, I should be using `\A` and `\z` here. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Bit late  though... However keep in mind that this regex approves of the name being `------`

Comment: Consider non-English speakers (names in Cyrillic etc.). It's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Any validation you perform here is likely to break down unless it is extremely general. For instance, enforcing a minimum length of 3 is probably about as reasonable as you can get without getting into the specifics of what is entered.

When you have names like "O'Malley" with an apostrophe, "Smith-Johnson" with a dash, "Andrés" with accented characters or extremely short names such as "Vo Ly" with virtually no characters at all, how do you validate without excluding legitimate cases? It's not easy.

Answer (score 1):

At least one space and at least 4 char (including the space)

```
\A(?=.* )[^0-9`!@#\\\$%\^&*\;+_=]{4,}\z
```